# Need to calculate the average from a loop java

Tags: java

This is the code it is supposed to simulate the rolls of 2 dice 5 times.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RollDice {

    static double die1;
    static double die2;
    static double sum;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String output = "";
        for (int i =0; i<5; i= i+1) {
            die1 = (Math.random()*6)+1;
            die1 = (int) die1;
            die2 = (Math.random()*6)+1;
            die2 = (int)die2;
            System.out.println("die 1 "+ die1+" die 2 "+ die2);

            sum = die1+die2;
            System.out.println("The sum is "+ sum);
            if(i>5) break;
        }

    }

}
```

I need to calculate the average for all the rolls not the average for each so the output shows the rolls the sum and the average of all the rolls.

Comment: Indent your code properly. Inside a loop which goes while i<5 a break at i>5 would be proof of a compiler bug, wouldn't it?

Comment: So what have you tried and what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify

```
die1 = (Math.random()*6)+1;
die1 = (int) die1;
```

To

```
die1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
```

But you don't need to cast it to an integer if you want exact values, thats going to truncate (get rid of) your decimal places.

To sum all rolls,

```
int total = 0;
int maxRolls = Integer.MAX_VALUE; //lol
for (int roll = 1; roll <= maxRolls; roll++) {
    // roll your dice
    total += (die1 + die2);
}
```

To Average

```
double average = (total / maxRolls);
```

To Output

```
System.out.println("Total: " + total + " Average: " + average + " Rolls: " + maxRolls);
```

You're welcome, now do your own homework

Answer (score 0):

If by average you mean the average across all the dice rolls, you can get it summing up all the rolls and dividing by 10.

```
static double total = 0;

// in your for loop
total += sum;

// after the loop
System.out.println("Average: "+(total/10));
```

Answer (score -1):

It can be something like this:

```
public class RollDice {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        int total;
        for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            int die1 = roll ();
            int die2 = roll();
            System.out.println("die 1 = " + die1 + " and die2 = " + die2);

            int sum = die1 + die2;
            System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);

            total += sum;
        }
        double avg = total / 5.0d;
        System.out.println("the avg is " + avg);
    }

    public int roll() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*6 + 1.0d);
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialize variable total to zero.

Comment: This does not even compile. Please fix it.